# Nodejs: Make a http request call and update the result to mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to make a REST API call to another application and update an existing mongoDB collection with the response.

I am able to do both separately but when I combine both its not working. Any idea what I am missing ?

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const args = process.argv;
const request = require('request');
var today = process.argv[2];

 var url = "<mongodburl>"
 MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
 if(err) {  console.log(err); }
 console.log("Connected to the DB Successfully");

 const options = {
                hostname: 'myapp.com',
                path: '/17/describe',
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Basic c3ZjLm5naS5jZLTFhv'
                 }
            };

      callback = function(response) {

            response.on('data', function (chunk) {
                  str += chunk;
            });

            response.on('end', function () {
                  console.log(str);
              callbackData(str);
            });
        }

      var req = http.request(options, callback).end();
      var cursor = db.collection("info").find({ 'day' : today });
      cursor.each(function(err,doc){
      if (doc != null){
      db.collection("cd_containers_info").findAndModify({"pod_name": 
      "j7c0k9"},[['_id','asc']],{$set :{"status":str}},{w:1},function(err, 
       result) {
          if (err) throw err;

       });
    }

  });
 db.close();
```

} );

Comment: Most of this code is not even valid. If you expect help with the code you have then you really need to show your real code. Too many things in here with unquoted strings. You may have altered parts before posting here, so don't do that. Debugging help means we need to see what you are really doing. Show your "separate" and "working" request also.

Comment: i have edited with actual code

Comment: Still really unclear. There are some clear problems but what do you think `db.collection("info").find({ 'day' : today })` is doing here? You're running that then iterating a cursor, but you're not actually using any of the results. So it's really unclear what you expect that to do. Even the `findAndModify()` which is actually a deprecated call you should not be using is really unclear whether that is actually what you need or whether you just found the code and thought you should use it.

Comment: It would probably help if you added a few paragraphs to the question to explain what the code is supposed to be doing.